# limit of $ \lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{ f_{n} (x)- f_{n-1} (x)}{ (1-x)^{n} }=? $

Tags: limits

> Let
>
> $$ f_{n} (x)= x^{ x^{\scriptstyle\cdot^{\scriptstyle\cdot^{\scriptstyle\cdot^{\scriptstyle x}}}}}$$
>
> Then
>
> $$
> \lim_{x \rightarrow 1}  \frac{ f_{n} (x)- f_{n-1} (x)}{ (1-x)^{n} }={?}
> $$

My try:

\begin{align}
\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{f_n-f_{n-1}}{(1-x)^{n}}
&=\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}{ \frac{ e^{\ln f_{n} (x) } - e^{\ln f_{n-1} (x) } }{(1-x)^{n}} } \\[6px]
&=\lim_{x \rightarrow 1}{ \frac{ e^{f_{n-1} (x)\ln x } - e^{f_{n-2} (x)\ln x } }{(1-x)^{n}} } \\[6px]
&=\lim_{x \rightarrow 1} \frac{\ln x(f_{n-1} (x)-f_{n-2} (x))}{ (1-x)^{n} }
\end{align}

Now?

Comment: You have almost done it. If the limit is $a_n$ then you have shown that $a_{n} =-a_{n-1}=(-1)^{n-2}a_{2}=(-1)^{n}$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh . please write. thank you .

Comment: I think you have solved the question almost. Just use the limit $\lim_{x\to 1}\dfrac{\log x} {1-x}=-1$ and then you get the desired relation $a_{n} =-a_{n-1}$. I am on a smartphone and it is difficult to type complete answers.

Comment: ln(x)=(x-1)-(x-1)^2/2+...

Answer (score 5):

You are extremely close to the solution. By setting $L_n=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{f_n(x)-f_{n-1}(x)}{(x-1)^n}$ we have

$$ L_1 = \lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x-1}{x-1}=1,\quad L_2=\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^x-x}{(x-1)^2}= 1$$
and
$$\begin{eqnarray*} L_n = \lim_{x\to 1}\frac{f_n(x)-f_{n-1}(x)}{(x-1)^n}&=&\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\exp(f_{n-1}(x)\log x)-\exp(f_{n-2}(x)\log x)}{(x-1)^n}\\&=&  \lim_{x\to 1}\frac{\log x}{x-1}\cdot \frac{f_{n-1}(x)-f_{n-2}(x)}{(x-1)^{n-1}}\\&\stackrel{d.H.}{=}&\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{f_{n-1}(x)-f_{n-2}(x)}{(x-1)^{n-1}}=L_{n-1}\end{eqnarray*}$$
hence it follows that $L_n=\color{red}{1}$ for any $n\geq 1$.

Comment: Perhaps a typo. The denominator is $(1-x)^{n}$ and this leads to $(-1)^{n}$ as answer.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: not a typo, I dealt with such form on purpose (for simplicity). Clearly the answer to the original question depends on a adjusted sign, $(-1)^n$.